# Why is face_recognition module not working for me in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition

I am making a face recognition script in Python. I am using the face_recognition module in Python. But when I run the code I get an output saying:-

```
Please install `face_recognition_models` with this command before using `face_recognition`:

pip install git+https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition_models

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I ran the command that it suggested and I also have the 'face_recognition_models' installed. But it is still asking me to install the module. Can you please help?

This is my code :-

```
import numpy as np
import face_recognition as fr
import cv2

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

my_image = fr.load_image_file("face.jpg")
my_face_encoding = fr.face_encodings(bruno_image)[0]

known_face_encondings = [my_face_encoding]
known_face_names = ["Adrian"]

while True:
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    rgb_frame = frame[:, :, ::-1]

    face_locations = fr.face_locations(rgb_frame)
    face_encodings = fr.face_encodings(rgb_frame, face_locations)

    for (top, right, bottom, left), face_encoding in zip(face_locations, face_encodings):

        matches = fr.compare_faces(known_face_encondings, face_encoding)

        name = "Unknown"

        face_distances = fr.face_distance(known_face_encondings, face_encoding)

        best_match_index = np.argmin(face_distances)
        if matches[best_match_index]:
            name = known_face_names[best_match_index]

        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), 2)

        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, bottom - 35), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
        cv2.putText(frame, name, (left + 6, bottom - 6), font, 1.0, (255, 255, 255), 1)

    cv2.imshow('Webcam_facerecognition', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: You need to talk to the author of the repo you are using. go to https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition_models and follow the link to the code repo where the proper usage of it is explained.

Answer (score 1):

If you would you deepface, then this could be handled in a few lines of code. Besides, it is keras based library. That's why, it is easy to install and run. On the other hand, face_recognition is mainly based on dlib and it is hard to install and run.

Here, you are expected to store facial images with .jpg or .png extention in the c:/facial_database folder.

```
#!pip install deepface
from deepface import DeepFace
DeepFace.stream(db_path = "C:/facial_database", model_name = 'Facenet')
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I have a question. By using deepface do we still get the same results as expected from face_recognition?

Comment: I need to be able to print name of the person by seeing the person using this script, can we do that using deep learning?

Comment: FaceNet got 99.65% and Dlib got 99.38% accuracy on LFW data set. So, you can get better results if you use facenet backend thand face_recognition. It is based on deep learning. And you can write the name of recognized identity.

Comment: Can you please send me the code for face net? I can't seem to find any tutorials for it. Please can you edit your answer for the FaceNet code? Thank you :)

Comment: I asked for the code of face net because the code you posted in the answer currently is not working, so can you please edit your answer and post the code? Thank you in advance

Comment: I did edit. Just pass Facenet to model_name parameter.

Comment: Does the db_path need to be C:/facial_database or can we put on another path like on desktop?

Comment: db_path could be any path. You just need to pass exact path. e.g. db_path = "C:/Users/Casey/Desktop/db". Then, you should store facial images in this path.

Comment: Ummmm... I tried the code that you edited but it gives me this error:-

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\poorn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Comment: So basically its saying that we need keras for deepface, and keras requires tensorflow version 2.21 or higher. But I have tensorflow 2.3.1 Why is it still showing this error?

Comment: I even tried only one line of code that is `import keras` and ran it. It is still showing the same error. please help me

Comment: Could you downgrade tensorflow to 1.9.0 and keras to 2.2.0?

Comment: But if I downgrade it to 1.9.0 then keras does not work right?

Comment: TF 1.9.0 and Keras 2.2.0 are compatible pairs

Comment: Oh, ok. Will do that asap :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem in the following way:

1. installed an older version of the dlib package: pip install dlib==19.21.1
2. used the --no-cache-dir flag: pip install --no-cache-dir face_recognition

Answer (score 0):

It seems that, at the time I am writing this answer, the module face_recognition doesn't work correctly on python 3.11.x or newer because I recieve your own output.
So if you want to use this module, you may follow these steps (these work for me):

1. verify your python version using: `python.exe --version` on Windows or `python3 --version` on Linux. If your version is 3.11.x or newer, uninstall python from your computer, then install python 3.10.x or older. In other cases you can keep that. It is clear that, if the output says that python is not installed on your machine, you need to install that, in this particular case the version 3.10.x (recommended) or older;
2. run these commands: `pip install cmake` and `pip install dlib`;
3. then install face_recognition module using: `pip install face_recognition`;

You can verify if it works running `pyhon.exe` on Windows or `python3` on Linux and writing in the interactive python shell the command `import face_recognition`. If this command gives no output, it means that the module works correctly.

I tested this process also on Ubuntu, where I use python 3.10.12, and it works.